# Measurement Protocol Only Tracks When I Provide cid (Doesn't' Track When I Only Provide uid)

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

Measurement protocol tracks when i send a hit with cid, but when i remove cid and use uid instead nothing is recorded.

I've waited for 48 hours.
I've looked in my userId enabled view.
I've enabled session unification

```
v=1
&t=transaction
&tid=UA-XXXXX-1
&ti=123456
&tr=9.99
&uid=123-456-789y180
&cid=
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is obvious, but the uid tracking only works if it has been assigned a cid previously through the front end. Using dummy data for testing won't work.